# Replace org.apache.cxf.helpers.DOMUtils.writeXml(Node n, OutputStream os) missing in Apache CXF version 3.1.16

Tags: java, soap, jboss, cxf

I'm migrating from `JBoss EAP 6.4` to `EAP 7.1`. I've updated Apache CXF from 2.7.14 to 3.1.16 but now I'm missing the `DOMUtils.writeXml(Node n, OutputStream os)` method. Which is the best way to replace it in a scenario like this?

```
SOAPMessage soapMessage = message.getContent(SOAPMessage.class);
SOAPBody env = soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
DOMUtils.writeXml(env, baos);
String soapBody = baos.toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've replaced `DOMUtils.writeXml(Node n, OutputStream os)` using `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory`:

```
SOAPMessage soapMessage = message.getContent(SOAPMessage.class);
SOAPBody env = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody();
javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource source = new javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource(env);
StringWriter stringResult = new StringWriter();
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(source, new StreamResult(stringResult));
String soapBody = stringResult.toString();
```